# Proof of Abel's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series

I tried to prove:

If $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is a power series that converges at $x= R > 0$ then it converges uniformly on $[0,R]$.

Please can you check my proof?

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Goal is to find $N$ with $n,m > N$ implies

$$ |a_{m+1}R^{m+1}{x^{m+1}\over R^{m+1}} + \dots + a_n R^n {x^n \over R^n}|<\varepsilon$$

Because by assumption $g(R) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n R^n < \infty$ there is $N$ such that $n,m>N$ implies

$$ |a_{m+1}R^{m+1}+ \dots + a_n R^n |<\varepsilon$$

Also, for $x \in [0,R]$, ${x \over R }\le 1$. Therefore for $n,m > N$

$$ |a_{m+1}R^{m+1}{x^{m+1}\over R^{m+1}} + \dots + a_n R^n {x^n \over R^n}| \le |a_{m+1}R^{m+1}{x^{m+1}\over R^{m+1}} + \dots + a_n R^n {x^{m+1} \over R^{m+1}}|\le |a_{m+1}R^{m+1}\cdot 1 + \dots + a_n R^n \cdot 1|  
<\varepsilon$$

Comment: why $|a_{m+1}R^{m+1}{x^{m+1}\over R^{m+1}} + \dots + a_n R^n {x^n \over R^n}| \le |a_{m+1}R^{m+1}{x^{m+1}\over R^{m+1}} + \dots + a_n R^n {x^{m+1} \over R^{m+1}}|$ ?

Comment: @user8268 because $s= {x \over R}\le 1$ and then if $n > m$ then $s^n \le s^m$

Comment: so you suppose that all $a_k$'s are positive (or negative)?